# Kineticjs lyaer drag and node inside layer dragend conflict

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have a layer in Kineticjs which I have more shapes in, see attached image:
[image: layer]
We can separate content of layer in two parts:
1. the object (the rectangle)
2. the selection nodes (4 corners) which we can scale the object from and rotation sign where we can rotate the object from

I have event handler on layer drag (because I need to move all the elements in the same time) and i have event handlers on scaling nodes and rotation sign as well. the problem is that when the nodes and rotation sign's drag (end, start, move) are triggered, automatically the layers drag events are triggered as well.

I have tried setting `layer.setListening(false)` then back to `true` but it has no result.
How can I make that the layer's events not to be triggerend while dragging the scaling nodes and rotation sign?

**[EDIT]**
Here's an UML diagram to see the structure of my layers. Each layer is added directly to stage:
[image: UML diagram of the layer]

Answer (score 0):

You might put all your elements (rects, etc) in one Kinetic.Group and your scale+rotation anchors in a second Kinetic.Group.

That way you can move all the rects at the same time by moving their group.

And you can set listening false on the rects layer when you want to drag the scale/rotation anchors.

You can still cause the rects to move when the scale/rotation anchors move using setX/setY.

Comment: I have attached an UML diagram of my layers. This is how my layers are structured. 
Moving items is possible by dragging the layer in my case. I chose rather moving layer then moving object only because as you see I have grSel group which contains the nodes that appear on selection. These objects must move with layer at same time. 
This works well, but it seems when I drag the scaling node then automatically layers drag events are triggered too. This is not good for me as both of these add one entry to the history array, but only one is needed.